# Symfony2 - Class X is not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

After working for several months, suddenly I'm getting this error when I try and run a command from the terminal. The "X" is a User entity, extending the FOSUserBundle.

Looking at some of the similar questions on here, the common errors seem to be incorrect annotations, not registering the bundle in the AppKernel, or not having auto_mapping enabled in the config.

The user class starts (I don't think the properties are necessary?) like this:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table()
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    // ...
}
```

The bundle is registered in the AppKernel:

```
  $bundles = array(
        // ...
        new Acme\UserBundle\UserBundle(),
        // ...
  );
```

Auto mapping is enabled (and not disabled in either the _prod or _dev configs) as you can see here:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true
```

Plus the FOSUserBundle is being told the correct entity to use:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

Doesn't work?

I stumbled upon one question on here where it was solved by disabling eAccelerator. We do have eAccelerator running on the server, but after clearing the cache I've verified the local value in the phpinfo() output is disabled when running the command, as was already expected:

```
eaccelerator.enable => 0 => 1
eaccelerator.optimizer => 0 => 1
```

When I run the `doctrine:mapping:info` command I can see that my UserBundle is missing. I'm at  a complete loss here as to what is missing or incorrect. Does anybody have any suggestions? It's worth mentioning that the front-end of the website works fine, which makes use of the User entity.

Comment: Did you try to specify the mapping location + type (annotation) manually in `config.yml` ? The config key is `doctrine.orm.entity_managers.<manager-name>.mapping` - see the [configuration reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html). **double-check** your namespaces aswell and clear your cache. Please report back afterwards :)

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue and it was a sleepy mistake to remove the EntityRepository with the whole @Entity line, causing the "not a valid entity" error.

I spent a lot searching for the issue with the `FOSUserBundle:User` superclass map but the problem was on my class, I had to know that when it didnt appear on `doctrine:mapping:info`.